# Query with SUM and DECODE and other columns error by GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query where I am selecting the customer number, I do a DECODE where I have the measurement data of the location and the sum of the net value of the invoice in a SUM function. I call this data from a table of invoice data.

The problem occurs with the SUM function when I try to run the query I get the following error:

**00934. 00000 - "group function is not allowed here."
*Cause:

*Action:
Error in row: 18 Column: 6**

```
SELECT CLT_NOMBRE1, --name of customer
    
    DECODE(zpk, NULL, MAX(zpk) OVER (PARTITION BY factura_ha, facturanumero,locacion) MELO,
    
    SUM (fct_neto) fct_neto
    
    FROM tbl_facturas
    WHERE NETOZ !=0 
                    AND lugar_lectura = '902'
                    AND anio =  '2023'

    GROUP BY CLT_NOMBRE1,
    DECODE(zpk, NULL, MAX(zpk) OVER (PARTITION BY factura_ha, facturanumero,locacion)
```

I have searched the internet for a solution and in many cases I read that I must leave out of the GROUP BY the aggregation field in this case SUM (fac_neto) but for the other two fields CLT_NOMBRE1 and DECODE (MELO) I must include them there. In the case of CASE all the complete statement without the alias. I have tried it but it does not work. Someone could tell me what could be wrong, I have been trying to solve it for several days but without success.

Comment: An initial point - your case statement doesn't make sense.  If zpk is Null, then select the MAX() of zpk?  The MAX() of a Null value is always going to be Null.  If, however, you're meant to be getting the MAX() value of zpk when it is NOT Null, then I suspect that you actually don't need the CASE at all

Comment: @Craig, thank you for your reply. I edited the question. I have changed the CASE statement for a DECODE statement but it doesn't work I mean I receive the same erro that before.

Comment: I believe you cannot have an aggregate function - in your case, MAX() - as part of your GROUP BY.  Anyway, grouping by the Customer Name, and then trying to show their SUM() of "fct_neto", but also wanting to partition the MAX() of "zpk" ..... it really doesn't make sense.  Are you expecting to only see 1 row per customer?

Comment: The issue is that this is a part of a correlated subquery that I have received to optimize. This query was done by someone else earlier. The expected results are the data from the invoices are to be shown separately.
You are right with this DECODE thing as you mention, but the tables where the data comes from require to do this operation. the Decode statement works  with the normal columns like CLT_NOMBRE1 but when I try to put an aggregation statement like SUM the query doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are missing a closing bracket for the `DECODE`.
2. More fundamentally, analytic functions are evaluated after aggregation functions. You need to use a sub-query to force the evaluation order to be reversed:

```sql
SELECT CLT_NOMBRE1,
       melo,
       SUM(fct_neto) AS fct_neto
FROM   (
  SELECT CLT_NOMBRE1,
         CASE
         WHEN zpk IS NULL
         THEN MAX(zpk) OVER (PARTITION BY factura_ha, facturanumero,locacion)
         ELSE NULL
         END as MELO,
         fct_neto
  FROM   tbl_facturas
  WHERE  NETOZ !=0 
  AND    lugar_lectura = '902'
  AND    anio =  '2023'
)
GROUP BY
       CLT_NOMBRE1,
       melo;
```

*Note: you could use the `DECODE` function instead of a `CASE` expression; however, `CASE` is in the ANSI standard whereas `DECODE` is Oracle specific.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bnOj1k5t)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much now I know hoy to solve this type of functions.